# VBA code runs slow because of referencing with other spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code that counts how many rows there are in a table and then extracts data from every other row (spreadsheet A). I have another spreadsheet (spreadsheet B) that grabs data from the output of this code using Match and Indirect formulas. When I run the code with only spreadsheet A open it runs very fast. If I have spreadsheet B open while I run the code in spreadsheet A it runs a lot slower, I'm guessing because it's trying to grab data while the code is running. Is there a way I can have the code run and stop the other spreadsheet from accessing the data until the code is finished? It's inconvenient to close spreadsheet B every time i need to run the code.

```
Sub GetTopForces()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i, j, count, cell As Integer

    count = 0
    cell = 1
    i = 0
    j = 0

' get count
    Do While cell <> 0
      cell = Cells(count + 4, 1).Value      
      count = count + 1      
    Loop

' get forces on top of column only
    Do While i < count
      Cells(4 + i, 16).Value = Cells(5 + j, 1).Value
      Cells(4 + i, 17).Value = Cells(5 + j, 2).Value
      Cells(4 + i, 18).Value = Cells(5 + j, 3).Value
      Cells(4 + i, 19).Value = -1 * Cells(5 + j, 5).Value
      Cells(4 + i, 20).Value = Cells(5 + j, 9).Value
      Cells(4 + i, 21).Value = Cells(5 + j, 10).Value

      i = i + 1
      j = j + 2   
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My knowledge in VBA is basic so I appreciate any advice. Thank you :)

Comment: Providing your code doesn't rely on any Excel formulas being recalculated while the code is running, set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` (and set it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` when you finish)

Comment: Alright - who upvoted my comment when it still said `= False` :D  (I nearly died of shame when I noticed that error in the comment!)

Comment: As an aside, you have declared i, j and count as variants, not integers...by not including the type for each one.

Comment: Also if you do not want to close the sheet to run you will need to assign the parent sheet to **ALL** Range objects: `WorkSheets("Sheet1").Cells(...`

Comment: That did it! thank you all